# InvalidProgramException profiling a WebForms app using Ninject

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, visual-studio-2012, ninject

I consistently receive an InvalidProgramException from Ninject when starting the profiler in Visual Studio 2012. I use instrumentation on an ASP.NET web application. Upon start the profiler adds its own functionality to the application through VSEnterpriseHelper.axd. It is when this module is initialized that ninject blows up. I receive an error message saying:

```
"The web site could not be configured correctly; getting ASP.NET process information failed. Requesting 'http://localhost:7777/VSEnterpriseHelper.axd' returned an error: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error."
```

The 500 internal server error can be observed in windows event viewer:

```
Event code: 3005 
Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred. 
Event time: 2013-10-31 11:26:11 
Event time (UTC): 2013-10-31 10:26:11 
Event ID: 8b04f14a2d78430d995bb8d4d6c61728 
Event sequence: 4 
Event occurrence: 1 
Event detail code: 0 

Application information: 
    Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-130276887605936349 
    Trust level: Full 
    Application Virtual Path: / 
    Application Path: C:\TFS\MyCompany Projects\Main\www\ 
    Machine name: JEGO 

Process information: 
    Process ID: 7876 
    Process name: w3wp.exe 
    Account name: MyCompany\august 

Exception information: 
    Exception type: InvalidProgramException 
    Exception message: Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program.
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers._CompileMethod(IRuntimeMethodInfo method)
   at System.Reflection.Emit.DynamicMethod.CreateDelegate(Type delegateType)
   at Ninject.Injection.DynamicMethodInjectorFactory.Create(ConstructorInfo constructor)
   at Ninject.Planning.Strategies.ConstructorReflectionStrategy.Execute(IPlan plan)
   at Ninject.Infrastructure.Language.ExtensionsForIEnumerableOfT.Map[T](IEnumerable`1 series, Action`1 action)
   at Ninject.Planning.Planner.CreateNewPlan(Type type)
   at Ninject.Planning.Planner.GetPlan(Type type)
   at Ninject.Activation.Context.Resolve()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Ninject.Activation.Providers.StandardProvider.Create(IContext context)
   at Ninject.Activation.Context.Resolve()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<CastIterator>d__b1`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Ninject.Web.Common.NinjectHttpModule.Init(HttpApplication context)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext)



Request information: 
    Request URL: http://localhost:7777/VSEnterpriseHelper.axd 
    Request path: /VSEnterpriseHelper.axd 
    User host address: ::1 
    User:  
    Is authenticated: False 
    Authentication Type:  
    Thread account name: MyCompany\august 

Thread information: 
    Thread ID: 7 
    Thread account name: MyCompany\august 
    Is impersonating: False 
    Stack trace:    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers._CompileMethod(IRuntimeMethodInfo method)
   at System.Reflection.Emit.DynamicMethod.CreateDelegate(Type delegateType)
   at Ninject.Injection.DynamicMethodInjectorFactory.Create(ConstructorInfo constructor)
   at Ninject.Planning.Strategies.ConstructorReflectionStrategy.Execute(IPlan plan)
   at Ninject.Infrastructure.Language.ExtensionsForIEnumerableOfT.Map[T](IEnumerable`1 series, Action`1 action)
   at Ninject.Planning.Planner.CreateNewPlan(Type type)
   at Ninject.Planning.Planner.GetPlan(Type type)
   at Ninject.Activation.Context.Resolve()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Ninject.Activation.Providers.StandardProvider.Create(IContext context)
   at Ninject.Activation.Context.Resolve()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<CastIterator>d__b1`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Ninject.Web.Common.NinjectHttpModule.Init(HttpApplication context)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext)
```

In the stacktrace above, the constructor parameter for:

```
Ninject.Injection.DynamicMethodInjectorFactory.Create(ConstructorInfo constructor)
```

holds the constructor for System.Func< IKernel >.

And this is the startup configuration we use (Ninject.Web.Common):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using MyCompany.Classlib.Misc;
using Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.DynamicModuleHelper;
using Ninject;
using Ninject.Web.Common;
using MyCompany;

[assembly: PreApplicationStartMethod( typeof( NinjectWebCommon ), "Start" )]
namespace MyCompany
{
    public static class NinjectWebCommon
    {
        private static readonly Bootstrapper __bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper();

        /// <summary>
        /// Starts the application
        /// </summary>
        public static void Start()
        {
            DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule( typeof( Ninject.Web.NinjectHttpModule ) );
            DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule( typeof( OnePerRequestHttpModule ) );
            DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule( typeof( NinjectHttpModule ) );
            __bootstrapper.Initialize( CreateKernel );
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Stops the application.
        /// </summary>
        public static void Stop()
        {
            __bootstrapper.ShutDown();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates the kernel that will manage your application.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>The created kernel.</returns>
        private static IKernel CreateKernel()
        {
            var kernel = new StandardKernel();
            kernel.Bind<Func<IKernel>>().ToMethod( ctx => () => new Bootstrapper().Kernel );
            kernel.Bind<IHttpModule>().To<HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule>();

            RegisterServices( kernel );

            // Setup Ninject with DependencyResolver. Enables constructor injection in controller classes in the IntegrationApi (WebAPI). 
            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new NinjectDependencyResolver( kernel );

            return kernel;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Load your modules or register your services here!
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="kernel">The kernel.</param>
        private static void RegisterServices( IKernel kernel )
        {
            Kernel.Initialize( kernel );
            Module.Initialize( kernel );
        }
    }
}
```

Worth noting is that if the line:

```
var kernel = new StandardKernel();
```

Is replaced with:

```
var kernel = new StandardKernel( new NinjectSettings { UseReflectionBasedInjection = true } );
```

Everything works just fine. But this does not seem like the correct solution, seeing as code generation is faster and the default.

Does anyone know how to fix the InvalidProgramException in a way that still allows us to use the faster code generation-based injection method?

Comment: Turning the reflection based injection on worked for me, thanks.